# Как сохранить оставшийся Timeout? JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord

У меня есть свой Дискорд бот, хочу добавить команду, которая дает роль и забирает через определенный срок. Я постоянно редактирую бота и setTimeout в случае его кратких перезапусков естественно сбрасывается и роль в итоге не забирается. Ищу решение проблемы. Хотел как-то сделать через отдельный файл, в который будет записываться пользователь и его оставшееся время роли. Во время работы бота это значение будет постоянно редактироваться и во время перезапуска загружаться, но не могу дойти до решения. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать или хотя бы где искать.

Answer (score 1):

А если задавать не setTimeout а брать текущее время, прибавлять сколько нужно и перезаписывать в переменную?